# React Select disable options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues disabling certain options within a large list within a React Select element. I have around 6,500 options that get loaded into the select. At first I was having issues with the search functionality lagging but then I started using react-select-fast-filter-options which took care of that problem. Now the issue is that I need to disable certain options depending on the propType "picks". Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
import 'react-virtualized-select/styles.css'
import Select from 'react-virtualized-select'
import createFilterOptions from 'react-select-fast-filter-options';

let options = [];
if(typeof stockSearchStocks !== 'undefined') {
    //loads in all available options from backend by laying down a static js var
    options = stockSearchStocks
}
const filterOptions =  createFilterOptions({options});

class StockSearch extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        exchanges: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        onSelectChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        searchDisabled: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        picks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        stock_edit_to_show: PropTypes.number
    }

    /**
     * Component Bridge Function
     * @param stock_id stocks id in the database
     */
    stockSearchChange = (stock_id) => {
        this.props.onSelectChange(stock_id);
    }

     //this is my current attempt to at least 
     //disable options on component mount but this doesn't seem to be working
    componentWillMount = () => {
        console.log('picks!: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.picks));
        let pickIDs = this.props.picks.map((p) => p.stock_id);
        options = options.map((o) => {
            // console.log(pickIDs.indexOf(o.value));
            if(pickIDs.indexOf(o.value)) {
                // console.log('here is the option: ' + JSON.stringify(o));
                // console.log('here is the option: ' + o.disabled);
                o.disabled = true;
            }
        })

    }

    /**
     * handles selected option from the stock select
     * @param selectedOption
     */
    handleSelect = (selectedOption) => {
        this.stockSearchChange(selectedOption.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="stock-search-container">
                <Select
                    name="stock-search"
                    options={options}
                    placeholder="Type or select a stock here..."
                    onChange={this.handleSelect}
                    disabled={this.props.searchDisabled}
                    value={this.props.stock_edit_to_show}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default StockSearch;
```

I have tried filtering through the picks props and changing that options variable to include `disabled:true` but this lags the application and I'm not sure if that will work now that I'm using react-select-fast-filter-options as it seems to be doing some sort of indexing. Is there a way to filter through the options var to find all instances of the picks prop and disable those options quickly?

Answer (score 99):

```
isDisabled={this.props.disabled}
```

You are passing a wrong prop.. For v2, the prop is isDisabled.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/145

Comment: Why is this not documented anywhere?

Comment: It is documented [here](https://react-select.com/props)

Answer (score 53):

In react-select v2:

1. add to your array of options a property 'disabled': 'yes' (or any other pair to identify disabled options)
2. use isOptionDisabled props of react-select component to filter options based on 'disabled' property

Here's an example:

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  {label: "one", value: 1, disabled: true},
  {label: "two", value: 2}
]

render() {

 <Select id={'dropdown'}
         options={options}
         isOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled}>
 </Select>

}
```

More information about react-select props is in the [docs](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types) and here's an [example](https://react-select.com/advanced#replacing-builtins) they reference.

Answer (score 35):

use the following to disable an option.

```
import Select from 'react-select';

render() {
  const options = [
    {label: "a", value: "a", isDisabled: true},
    {label: "b", value: "b"}
  ];

  return (
    <Select
      name="myselect"
      options={options}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Comment: In the current version of `react-select`, the key is `isDisabled`, not `disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

```
isDisabled={ here your condition expression }
```

Your condition will yield `true` or `false` then accordingly. React select will be disabled and stop showing options.

Answer (score -3):

People are making it a JavaScript issue. I say make it a CSS one and simplify.
Use this

```
style={{display: month === '2' ? 'none' : 'block'}}
```

Like so...
There are only 28 days in February

```
const ComponentName =() => {

  const [month, setMonth] = useState("")
  const [day, setDay] = useState("")


return (
<>
<select 
onChange={(e) => {
    const selectedMonth = e.target.value;
    setMonth(selectedMonth)> 
   <option selected disabled>Month</option>
   <option value= '1'>January</option>
   <option value= '2'>February</option>
</select>

<select
onChange={(e) => {
    const selectedDay = e.target.value;
    setDay(selectedDay)> 
   <option selected disabled>Day</option>
   <option value= '28'>28</option>
   <option value= '29' style={{display: month === '2' ? 'none' : 'block'}}>29</option>
   <option value= '30'>30</option>
</select>

</>
)

}

export default ComponentName;
```

Comment: People are using an external library and looking for a way on how to disable options there in the right way.