# Disable IOS Select options menu in mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have autocomplete component in ReactJS and  when that component is opened by mobile device, if it has default value, Operating System selects default value and it is opening options menu for selected data. How can I disable that menu for mobile device ? In normal device (laptop, desktop etc) or android device this problem does not matter. I have faced that in IOS devices. Could you help me at this issue ? How can I fix it ?

**IOS Mobile device screenshot:**

[image]

**Android Mobile device screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: your link show me detect to user agent. I am looking for disable options menu if it is possible @John

Comment: How about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48789307/1471485, does it answer your question?